# how to make username and password or app as lock screen

Tags: android, screen-lock

i make a multi-user with restricted profile application

that Add user, delete user, login user

and Customized applications for each user.

the users and its information saved in sqllite database in device

[image: a multi-user with restricted profile application]

how to make this application as locker screen to device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make an App the default screen of any device.
Application needs to reside and function within the sandbox environment of the native OS in which it is installed.

If you are trying to make an app for multiple users, use the login screen as landing page.
Depending on the use-case you can then launch the app. Like home page for logged in user and login screen if user is not logged in/ has logged out before closing the app.

Kindly note every [activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) shall be associated with a activity life cycle.
[Android developer forum](http://developer.android.com/index.html) might be of interest for you.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.android.notepad">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_notes"
                 android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <provider android:name="NotePadProvider"
                  android:authorities="com.google.provider.NotePad" />

        <activity android:name="NotesList" android:label="@string/title_notes_list">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="NoteEditor"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
                  android:label="@string/title_note" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_edit">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="com.android.notepad.action.EDIT_NOTE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="TitleEditor" 
                  android:label="@string/title_edit_title"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_title">
                <action android:name="com.android.notepad.action.EDIT_TITLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

The first activity, NotesList, is distinguished from the other activities by the fact that it operates on a directory of notes (the note list) rather than on a single note. It would generally serve as the initial user interface into the application

Comment: thank you for help me 

what about  use the login screen as landing page ?

Comment: Use intent filter for that activity, provide the category as launcher. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html will give more insight on this.